# ios - ionic - firebase: Authentication with Google and Facebook doesn't return to app

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, ionic3

I have an app with Ionic3 on Firebase. When I authenticate with Google and Facebook it works nice on browser and Android devices. But it doesn't work on iOS, instead of returning to the app, I have a blank page on Safari:

[image]

The full URL it shows is: https://dime1vino.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler?code=....

I think it might be related with Associated Domains, but I don't know why.

This is my config.xml:

[image]
[image]

This is my AASA file: https://dime1vino.page.link/apple-app-site-association

I also have the Associated Domains on XCode:
[image]

And those are my Firebase iOS App settings:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: I have same issue.. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @user2570135 I'm sorry, i didn't see your comment. 

Yes, I find a solution. There was a problem or conflict with the  I just needed to change the CordobaWebViewEngine in config.xml:


`<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVUIWebViewEngine" />`